# Ethereum Stack Exchange is blacklisted

Tags: support

It looks like Ethereum Stack Exchange was recently blacklisted. I'm using a VPN with malware-blocking. Today I suddenly get this:

[image: screenshot]

I am able to circumvent this by clicking *visit the site anyway* but someone at Stack Exchange might want to look into why this site is on blacklists in first place.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but it might be helpful if you pasted the link here you are trying to visit and perhaps a screenshot of fhe "detailed report" you show above that explains the security risks they are alleging with this site.